# How does encrypting a bootloader prevent it from being unlocked

Tags: rooting, encryption, bootloader

As I'm waiting patiently (sigh) for the at&t note 4 root, I have been trying to understand the process of rooting.
This [website](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/05/27/so-you-want-to-know-about-bootloaders-encryption-signing-and-locking-let-me-explain/) does a good job of describing what a locked/unlocked bootloader is, but it doesn't explain why encrypting a bootloader makes it impossible to directly unlock it like an unencrypted one.  It mentions that some bootloaders are not "unlockable" but it doesn't go into detail.  So what about encrypting a bootloader makes it difficult to unlock, and what does encrypting it make it difficult to root (if it does)